# After Update to Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4, Error: Could not resolve aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-windows.jar

Tags: firebase, android-studio, gradle, internet-connection, android-studio-arctic-fox

After update to Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4,

```
Error: Could not resolve aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:7.0.4-7396180): No cached version

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform viewbinding-7.0.4.aar (androidx.databinding:viewbinding:7.0.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
.
.




Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

if I disable offline mode and syn the project again. Then even its not building the project then errors comes again.

Error after disabling offline mode:

```
:app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/cuberto/liquid-swipe/1.0.0/liquid-swipe-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/cuberto/liquid-swipe/1.0.0/liquid-swipe-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway


.
many errors
.
.

Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/cuberto/liquid-swipe/1.0.0/liquid-swipe-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

even offline mode is deactivated.

What's wrong with it?

Even Firebase is not connecting to internet through firebase Assistant though Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit for this in my project.
Earlier I was using in all projects repositories in build.gradle(Exam String)

```
maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
```

In earlier Android studio versions, it was working using this repositories.

After removing this from build.gradle(Exam String).

It started working fine.

It is used for liquide swipe view pager.

For reference I have added screenshot of repositories.
[image: Check screenshot of repositories]